# Equation of auxiliary circle of ellipse $2x^2+6xy+5y^2=1$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Equation of auxiliary circle of ellipse $2x^2+6xy+5y^2=1$

My attempt:
I know that auxiliary circle means that it has the diameter of major axis

To remove I tried axis of rotation method and got
$$\cot (2\theta)=-1/2
\\
x=x'\cos(\theta) -y'\sin(\theta)
\\
y=x'\sin(\theta) + y'\cos(\theta)$$
And put this is equation I am getting somewhere wrong. Please help.

Comment: plz tell your incorrect result and how you got it. We’re not mind-readers.

Comment: $\tan(2\theta)=-2$, so $\sin\theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\cos\theta=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}$. Now you need to replace $x$ by $$\frac{-x'-2y'}{\sqrt{5}} $$ and $y$ by $$\frac{2x'-y'}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: But how you get that sintheta value from tan 2theta

Answer (score 3):

Using [Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) values,

$$-\dfrac\pi2<2\theta<0,\cos2\theta=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^22\theta}}=?$$

$$\sin\theta=-\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos2\theta}2}=?$$

$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos2\theta}2}=?$$